# How to add a ContextIndicator or a FlipViewIndicator from the code behind?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Callisto has a tool named FlipViewIndicator which acts as a context indicator, Now i know how to add the indicator from the xaml itself

```
<StackPanel>
<FlipView x:Name="MyFlipView"/>
<callisto:FlipViewIndicator FlipView="{Binding ElementName=MyFlipView}" />
</StackPanel>
```

How can i add the FlipViewIndicator from the code behind ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like (after adding a name to the StackPanel)

```
MyStackPanel.Children.Add(new FlipViewIndicator { FlipView = MyFlipView });
```